# how to parse a datetime in javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, mysql

How can I parse the following string :

```
 02/16/2015 10:51 PM
```

into this

```
 2015-02-16 22:51
```

The reason I want to do this is because mysql is returning an error if I try to enter the first one with the following code :

```
<script>

var d = Date.parse("02/16/2015 10:51 PM");
alert(d); // 1424123460000

</script>
```

Tried with both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME column types. Any help ?

Comment: how do you get that date string?

Comment: What's your server side language between these two layers? PHP?

Comment: Yes @War10ck it's PHP

Comment: @RafikBari your server side should be handling this, not the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment.js` is a nice library that handles datetime stuff related in JS. You should try it. http://momentjs.com/

```
moment("any datetime string", "format of input string").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
moment("02/16/2015 10:51 PM").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") // 2015-02-16 22:51:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already tried that with moment("02/16/2015 10:51 PM").unix() but it gave me a number like 265165165 which cannot be inserted into db as well ?!

Comment: here is a jsbin using your example code - <http://jsbin.com/masenuwodo/1/edit?html,js,output>

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in your server side code using the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions:

```
$str = "02/16/2015 10:51 PM";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($str));
```

**Output:**

```
2015-02-16 22:51
```

With this method, you would modify the date server side before sending it to the client.

Comment: hi @War10ck Look like your answer makes sense. I'm passing $str through ajax?  should I convert it to base64 first ? For some reason, i couldn't pass the variable as it is ?

Comment: You could try generating JSON with it (i.e `echo json_encode(array("date" => date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($str))));`). The in JavaScript you would access it like so `result.date` where `result` is the returned payload from the AJAX call.function as shown above.